# how do I pass parameters when attaching a method to an event in c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am trying to send parameters to a method which is called by an event when attaching the event listener, I can create the parameters in an anonymous method which works fine however I would Ideally like to make it more concise as in the example below, this is throwing the following compiler error:

> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.EventHandler' and 'void'

```
ConfigFileWritten += (sender, args) =>
{
    string prefix = "IFMDE";
    bool enabled = true;

    SetConfigInterfaceEnabled(prefix, enabled);
};

//this line is throwing a compiler error 
ConfigFileWritten += SetConfigInterfaceEnabled("",true);
```

Is it possible to refacor the code as I am proposing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not like that. What you are doing there is attempting to attach *the result of calling* `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` as an event handler, which is of course not possible (the result would have to be an `EventHandler` delegate, but it's just `void`).

What you can do is

```
ConfigFileWritten += (s, e) => SetConfigInterfaceEnabled("",true);
```

Here the event handler is a lambda function with the appropriate signature (takes two implicitly typed parameters) that in turn calls `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled`. Its only purpose is to adapt the signature of `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` to the `EventHandler` that is expected.

For completeness I should mention that although it's very unusual to need to do this, you can have a syntax like you proposed if `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` is a factory method that creates delegates:

```
EventHandler SetConfigInterfaceEnabledDelegate(string s, bool b)
{
    return (o, e) => SetConfigInterfaceEnabled(s, b);
}

ConfigFileWritten += SetConfigInterfaceEnabledDelegate("", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more concise by not using variables for the parameters that you pass by value, like this:

```
ConfigFileWritten += (sender, args) => {
    SetConfigInterfaceEnabled("IFMDE", true);
};
```

When the compiler sees the above, it does not call `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` right away. Instead, it creates an object that can be invoked at runtime, such that when you invoke it, the `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` gets called. In other words, the `=>` creates a delegate that lets you postpone a call to `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled`.

However, when compiler sees this

```
ConfigFileWritten += SetConfigInterfaceEnabled("IFMDE", true);
```

it interprets it as an instruction to call `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` *immediately*, and use the delegate returned from it as the event handler. Of course it's not possible, because `SetConfigInterfaceEnabled` does not return a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If `ConfigFileWritten` event handler is in your own type you can pass argumemns when rising event. Derive your own event arguments type from `EventArgs` and pass you arguments. It can give you more flexibility and you don't have to hardcode arguments in event handler.